# FreeRADIUS 2 should use a different Python than default

Tags: python, centos5, freeradius2

We've got a FreeRADIUS 2 deamon installed on a CentOS 5.7 server.

We'd like to use a pre-written Python module to do authorization but there's a problem: The Python module we've got requires **Python 2.6** or more but the Python that comes installed with CentOS is **Python 2.4**.

Now, the server admin have installed Python 2.6 in a separate folder `/usr/lib/Python2.6` so we can run Python 2.6 from there. However, `/usr/bin/python` is still Python 2.4. Apparently, replacing the default Python 2.4 will cause all kinds of problems.

Is there any way I can force FreeRADIUS to use `/usr/lib/Python2.6` instead of the default 2.4 to locate and run modules?

Comment: Can't the script be modified to run from a specific path?

Comment: I think you try to export PATH variable in freeradius startup script. In the exported value, you can specify `/usr/lib/` as first path and then append the default other paths like `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. You may need also to symlink python2.6 to python.

Comment: Symlinking Python won't work since that'll break stuff for CentOS. Specifying the path in the script, didn't try that. Will check.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the init script (something like `/etc/init.d/freeradius`).  You then need to locate the line where it's launching the application, and change any instance of `python` to `/usr/lib/Python2.6`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the 2.6 Python directly by listing the full path. So, if your script was called FreeRADIUS.py, your script would read `/usr/lib/Python2.6/FreeRADIUS.py`.